# How can I get Facebook userName by userID using Asp.net?

Tags: android, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am doing an App for android

now I can using "Facebook SDK for Android" to get userID and store in SQL server

The problem is ..

> **how can I use "Asp.net 4.0" (visual web developer 2010) and "Facebook SDK for .NET" to parse these ID to userName on  Server
>   without login button?**

I have found some information for using dynamic access token.

but all I have found examples are using visual 2013 , MVC , login button

that is not what i want. I just want a basic aspx.

Do anybody know anything about the question ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBRlj.jpg
[image]

Comment: What are you doing? Trying to run ASP.NET on Android?

Comment: I need to show the user information in Android(Client). The info will store in SQL Server ; and I use ASP.net(Server) to integrate these data. Now I need to show them on Android..

Comment: Now your question is unclear. Are you trying to access Facebook data from Android, or from ASP.NET? Either way, the examples you found with MVC should be fairly straightforward to convert, because .NET code for MVC is still just .NET code. The only thing that changes is the GUI and GUI related code.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I am trying to get dynamic access token and using userid to get username on asp.net.

Comment: Try to come up with something based on the tutorials you found. All the backend code will be similar between Web Forms and MVC. If you then have a specific problem, feel free to come to us. But as it stands now, your question is too broad to attempt to answer.

Comment: OK, thank you :) I already resolve my problem \(^o^)/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook doesn't provide username. If you are looking for name of user then use this code

**Get accesstoken from here.**
**Step 1 :** http://narendrajarad.blogspot.in/2014/07/facebook-login-using-javascript.html

**Step 2 :** Add Facebook reference to your project from nuget packages.

**Use this name space :**

`using Facebook;`

**Use this code :**

```
_apiKey = "API KEY"
_apiSecret = "SECRET KEY"
var accessToken = "Pass accesstoken stored id hidden field" // check in above link
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic me = client.Get("me");
Response.Write(me.first_name + "" + me.last_name);
```

If you are looking for more functionality in facebook using c# let me know. I can surely help you.